# FreeFem++: Tangential trace in boundary condition?

Tags: freefem++

I want to use Nédélec's elements in FreeFem++ to solve Maxwell's equations in 3D. My problem is that I don't find a way to write the boundary condition which is E × N = F. I tested:

`on(0, Ehy * N.z - Ehz * N.y = Fx, Ehz * N.x - Ehx * N.z = Fy, Ehx * N.y - Ehy * N.x = Fz)`

but an error is displayed, and the only thing it says is that there is an error "before token =". If I change the boundary condition to a random one like `on(0, Ehx = Fx, Ehy = Fy, Ehz = Fz)` it doesn't throw any error so I think the issue comes from the arithmetics operations in the condition.

Any idea?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, your second attempt in indeed the right one! May I ask you if you know how to implement Neumann boundary conditions for Nedelec elements?

Comment: Hi, actually it's not the right thing to do, as it won't work as expected. Please refer to the answer I added below to get the real solution to the issue. About Neumann conditions, it's difficult to give a solution without having them but, in general, this type of condition is included in the variational equation so there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `on(0, Ehx = Fx, Ehy = Fy, Ehz = Fz)` won't produce a compilation error, but it won't produce the right solution neither.

There is a workaround to get the right solution, with the right boundary condition: having a function f such that f × n = E × n. That way, you can write `on(0, Ehx = fx, Ehy = fy, Ehz = fz)` and it will work as expected.

If you only have F but you know exactly the boundary of the domain you can compute f = n × F. Basic operations will convince you that f × n = E × n.

Comment: Yep! That's right! Sorry, I misunderstood what you wrote above. What about Neumann conditions?